# Prepend space before binding text (knockout.js)

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

How would I prepend whitespace in knockout.js text?

Without knockout.js I have:

```
<span class=“some-icon”> myNumber</>
                        ^
                        |_ _ this whitespace
```

My value is a number in my viewmodel. And if I add the following knockout binding, the space is removed and the numbers become unnecessarily very close to my icon

```
span class=“some-icon” data-bind=“text: myNumber”> value</>
```

Comment: Try using the html entity `&nbsp;`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could do this:

```
<span class="some-icon" data-bind="text: ' ' + myNumber()"></span>
```

But you should probably just use CSS instead to fix this problem. Using spaces is not a very nice solution.

Comment: `' ' + myNumber()` if it's an observable

Comment: I ended up with the CSS as that seems a noble route.